# 2007 Saturn Aura power steering fluid loss

Tags: saturn, aura

I had an oil change on my car as well as a new air filter. Later in the day the power steering dropped and started whining. When I checked the reservoir, it was empty! Just wondering if an oil change technician somehow damaged the pump! Is this a possibility, or just coincidence?

Comment: The ps pump generally isn't in the area you'd be in when changing oil. Why do you suspect the pump? Did you see the fluid leak out of it?

Comment: Is there fluid on the ground after the vehicle is parked overnight? This would indicate a possible leak somewhere. Most oil change places check all fluids. Check your paperwork to see if they indicate that check. If not, it could just be coincidence.